# Many-to-Many relationship in EF Core with dependent and principal entity both being the same type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Imagine this class for a data model used with Entity Framework:

```
public class CriteriaCatalogue : BaseDataModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<CriterionToCriteriaCatalogueLink> CriteriaLinks { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CriteriaCatalogueToCriteriaCatalogueLink> CatalogueChildren { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CriteriaCatalogueToCriteriaCatalogueLink> CatalogueParents { get; set; }
    // a bunch of additional properties with custom getters and setters to more easily access and create the child/parent `CriteriaCatalogue`s
}
```

The property `CriteriaLinks` gets filled perfectly, but my Parent and Children lists linking to the same type don't work at all, they get filled with the same object (so when looking at Owner1, both the children will be Owner1 and the parents will be Owner1)

So while the following is valid code, and will work as expected as long as you don't let EF touch it, EF will remove one of the connections:

```
CriteriaCatalogue owned = new CriteriaCatalogue { Name = "Owned" };
CriteriaCatalogue owner1 = new CriteriaCatalogue { Name = "Owner1", CriteriaCatalogues = new List<CriteriaCatalogue> { owned } };
CriteriaCatalogue owner2 = new CriteriaCatalogue { Name = "Owner2", CriteriaCatalogues = new List<CriteriaCatalogue> { owned } };
```

If you save all three objects to a database through EF, this is the result:
`owned` doesn't have any children or parents.
`owner1` has owner1 as child and owner1 as parent.
`owner2` has owner2 as child and owner2 as parent.

How do I configure EF correctly to allow that `owned` can belong to several other entities?

## Edit 2: I got it to work. All I needed to do was switch the CatalogueChildren and CatalogueParents references in the OnModelCreating method:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<CriteriaCatalogueToCriteriaCatalogueLink>(cctcc =>
        {
            cctcc.HasKey(cctcc => new { cctcc.ChildId, cctcc.ParentId });

            cctcc.HasOne(cctcc => cctcc.Child)
                .WithMany(children => children.CatalogueParents)
                .HasForeignKey(cctcc => cctcc.ChildId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

            cctcc.HasOne(cctcc => cctcc.Parent)
                .WithMany(parents => parents.CatalogueChildren)
                .HasForeignKey(cctcc => cctcc.ParentId);
        });
```

## Edit: Here's my full implementation according to Sergey's answer:

### Linking class:

```
public class CriteriaCatalogueToCriteriaCatalogueLink
{
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual CriteriaCatalogue Parent { get; set; }
    public Guid ChildId { get; set; }
    public virtual CriteriaCatalogue Child { get; set; }
}
```

### DbContext.OnModelCreating snippet:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<CriteriaCatalogue>(criterionCatalogue =>
        {
            criterionCatalogue.HasMany(cc => cc.CriteriaLinks);
            criterionCatalogue.HasMany(cc => cc.CatalogueChildren);
            criterionCatalogue.HasMany(cc => cc.CatalogueParents);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<CriterionToCriteriaCatalogueLink>(ctcc => 
        { 
            ctcc.HasKey(ctcc => new { ctcc.CriteriaCatalogueId, ctcc.CriterionId });

            ctcc.HasOne(ctcc => ctcc.Criterion)
                .WithMany(criterion => criterion.CriteriaCatalogueLinks)
                .HasForeignKey(ctcc => ctcc.CriterionId);

            ctcc.HasOne(ctcc => ctcc.CriteriaCatalogue)
                .WithMany(criteriaCatalogue => criteriaCatalogue.CriteriaLinks)
                .HasForeignKey(ctcc => ctcc.CriteriaCatalogueId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<CriteriaCatalogueToCriteriaCatalogueLink>(cctcc =>
        {
            cctcc.HasKey(cctcc => new { cctcc.ChildId, cctcc.ParentId });

            cctcc.HasOne(cctcc => cctcc.Child)
                .WithMany(children => children.CatalogueChildren)
                .HasForeignKey(cctcc => cctcc.ChildId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

            cctcc.HasOne(cctcc => cctcc.Parent)
                .WithMany(parents => parents.CatalogueParents)
                .HasForeignKey(cctcc => cctcc.ParentId);
        });
```

As you can see, the implementation for connecting `Criterion`s is a bit different but essentially the same. I tried the exact same for connecting `CriteriaCatalogue`s but it doesn't work. I think EF gave me an error regarding circle references when I tried that. Most importantly, it's still not possible for one `CriteriaCatalogue` to have serveral parents.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just ran out of ideas on what to google, and I'm sure this is just an option in the EF model.

Comment: I have a question about your example, after calling `SaveChanges`, `objectA.Id` is `1` or `2`? a child object cannot have two parents at the same time.

Comment: In this case the ID doesn't really matter. They are randomly generated GUIDs anyway. And, regarding whether it's possible, it certainly is. I just need to figure out how to set up EF to deal with it. As you can see in my implementation, I already set up a Linking class (so technically, yea, a child object doesn't have two direct parents but we can set up a model that basically achieves the same)

Comment: You are referencing an object as a child to two other parent objects. after saving data, 2 records show be inserted but in code, there are two `GUID` to be assigned to `Id` property and those records are related to one object. If you remove `objectA`, the child object of `objectB` will be removed, or `objectC` or EF should delete two rows in database for removeing one object?

Comment: The example is probably a bit confusing, since I am using the setter of that property (`CriteriaCatalogues`) to create linking objects, and store them in a seperate list (`CatalogueChildren` for example), and the getter only exposes the List of `CriteriaCatalogue`s instead of the List of linking objects

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code:

Create a new class

```
public class MyClassMyClass
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }

    public virtual MyClass Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual MyClass Child { get; set; }

}
```

and add this code to dbcontext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyClassMyClass>(entity =>
            {
              
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Child)
                    .WithMany(p => p.MyClassMyClassChildren)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ChildId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Parent)
                    .WithMany(p => p.MyClassMyClassParents)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ParentId);
            });
```

Fix your class:

```
public partial class MyClass
    {
       
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<MyClassMyClass> MyClassMyClassChildren { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MyClassMyClass> MyClassMyClassParents { get; set; }
    }
```

I tested it in VS2019 using this code:

```
MyClass objectA = new MyClass();
var objectB = new MyClassMyClass { Parent = new MyClass(), Child = objectA };
var objectC = new MyClassMyClass { Parent = new MyClass(), Child = objectA };


_context.MyClassMyClasses.AddRange(new MyClassMyClass[] { objectB, objectC });
 _context.SaveChanges();
```

Everything was working perfect.

Comment: I tried implementing it like this, but it still won't work. It works fine when parent and child are different classes though. I'll show my full implementation in my question.

Comment: I will accept your answer if I get it to work using your idea as a concept. Currently, it's not working for me. I even upvoted it for your effort, but as long as it doesn't work on my machine, I won't accept it.
Regardless, what exactly do you think is wrong with my implementation? when running that code, owner1 will have owner1 as parent and owner1 as child, while owner2 will have owner2 as parent and owner2 as child. owned will not have any children or parents.

Comment: Did you try my answer as it is?

Comment: Yes, to my understanding my current implementation is essentially the exact same (besides a bit of getter/setter fun that makes it easier to access children/parents). Maybe the OnModelCreating is messing it up for me? Notice I got a very similar concept to work with a different class being linked.

Comment: You should take my db context as it is, just change the names. This is why you can have the problems.

Comment: Even with everything removed from the OnModelCreating method, and just your code left over, it doesn't work.

Comment: I got it to work. All I had to do was switch the Parent and Child references in the OnModelCreating method

Comment: I am really glad that everything is working now.

Comment: If you'd like me to accept your answer, please fix the error in the OnModelCreating method / db context

Comment: I am sory but I am always testing my answers before posting. This code was tested and worked and still works perfectly.